# Posting new data to database

Tags: php, mysql

I can't get this to work, it is not posting data to the database, I am completely new to this and any help is great!

```
<?php
    $connection = mysql_connect('server', 'user', 'pass') or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db('db') or die(mysql_error());

    $client = $_POST['client'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $amount = $_POST['amount'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO $sales (client, date, amount) VALUES ('$client', '$date', '$amount')";

    $result = mysql_query($sql, $connection);

    if ($result) {
        echo "Successful";
        echo "<BR>";
        echo "<a href='insert.php'>Back to main page</a>";
    } else {
        echo "ERROR";
    }
?>
```

Comment: You should sanitize your post variables to prevent sql injection.

Comment: It's deprecated: Use mysqli_* instead of mysql_*

Comment: mysql_select_db('db') should have $connection defined:  mysql_select_db('db', $connection). BUT.. use mysqli instead

Comment: What is `$sales` here? And you should put `date` field into backqoutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is $sales looks like it should not be variable, assuming it as a tablename, try this

```
$sql="INSERT INTO sales (client, date, amount) VALUES ('$client', '$date', '$amount')";
```

Also, date is a reserve word in MYSQl, though it is accepted to use it without back tick operator, it would be good to escape it like this

```
 $sql="INSERT INTO sales (client, `date`, amount) VALUES ('$client', '$date', '$amount')";
```

Comment: No, date is not a [reserved word in MYSQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html). From the doc: _MySQL permits some keywords to be used as unquoted identifiers because many people previously used them. Examples are those in the following list:

ACTION

BIT

DATE_

Comment: @antoox you should read my answer properly "Also, date is a reserve word in MYSQl, though it is accepted to use it without back tick operator,"

Comment: @chandresh_cool Yes sorry for the noise. It adds, however, a little explanation.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have set your table name as a variable, which is fine, but you haven't defined it. Also, i'd highly recommend sanitizing your `$_POST` variables to prevent SQL injection.

> [Please, don't use mysql_* functions in new
> code.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-function-in-php)
> They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation
> process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799) has begun on it. See
> the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)?
> Learn about [prepared
> statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead,
> and use [PDO](https://www.php.net/pdo) or
> [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/mysqli) - this
> [article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will
> help you decide which.

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli('host', 'user', 'password', 'database');

$client = $_POST['client'];
$date   = $_POST['date'];
$amount = $_POST['amount'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO sales (client, `date`, amount) VALUES ('$client', '$date', '$amount')";
$result = $mysqli -> query($sql);
$num    = $mysqli -> affected_rows;

if($num == 1){
    echo 'Success';
}else{
    echo 'Error: '.$mysqli -> error;
}
```

Also, `date` is a reserved word in MySQL so i'd suggest using the back tick operators or maybe change the column name.